# How do I connect my Ublox neo 6M GPS Module with arduino mega 2560?

Tags: arduino-mega

I tried connecting RX of GPS to Pin 18 and TX of GPS to Pin 19 but I get an error that No GPS is detected,check wiring.VCC of GPS to 5V.

I have set baudrate to 115200.I am trying DeviceExample code of TinyGPS++ library.

Comment: Have you checked that is the correct baud rate?  Most GPS work at 19200.
If you want more information you need to flesh out the question.  Add a circuit diagram and a link to the GPS datasheet.

Answer (score 1):

The default baud rate for ublox NEO-6M GPS devices is 9600, **not** 115200.

And try [NeoGPS](https://github.com/SlashDevin/NeoGPS).  It's smaller, faster, more accurate, more reliable and it comes pre-configured to use `Serial1` on a Mega.  Be sure to read the Installation instructions.  If it doesn't work, follow the Troubleshooting pages and try NMEAdiagnostic.ino.

NeoGPS has an example sketch (ubloxRate.ino) that can configure the NEO-6M to other baud rates, once you get the basic programs working at 9600.